# I'm getting all sorts of errors when using MUI theme provider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the primary color of the mui theme, but when I apply it, i get all sorts of errors. Here's my code:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/system";
import "./App.css";
import IntegrationsPage from "./pages/integrations/IntegrationsPage";

function App() {

  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#4B68FE",
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <IntegrationsPage/>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here are the errors. The errors dont appear when I don't set the theme.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
    at Paper (Paper.js:81:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
Paper @ Paper.js:81
```

Do I need to set all the theme values? What if I only want to change the primary color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are passing your new `theme` to the `provider` you are not updating the theme.

if you want to change the primary color, you should change it inside the file from which you are importing your theme.

and if you don't have any theme, your code is fine you just need to import `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` from `@mui/material/styles`

Comment: how do i update the theme? can you give a better example?

Comment: do you have a `theme` or you are giving the `theme` attribute for the first time to your `ThemeProvider` ? if it's the case then you are creating a `theme` you are not updating and the issue should be in from where you are importing `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` look at the last part of my answer

Comment: I dont really have a theme. I dont want to touch anything other than the primary color. I just want the primary color changed.

Comment: did you read the last part of my answer ? your imports are incorrect

Comment: Yes. I did. Sorry I was overwhelmed I didn't quite understand it the first few times I read it.